# How can I scroll to a given position?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I use UIScrollView. I need to scroll in a given position. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```

where CGPointMake(x, y) is the point to which you want to scroll :-)